# Order of generators in Scala "for comprehension" affects answer

Tags: scala

I'm new to Scala, and I'm working through *Scala for the Impatient* by Cay Horstmann. It was going well until I got to for comprehension, and came up against this slightly cryptic passage (section 2.6, Advanced for Loops and for Comprehensions):

[Start quote]

The generated collection is compatible with the first generator.

```
for (c <- "Hello"; i <- 0 to 1) yield (c + i).toChar
  // Yields "HIeflmlmop"
for (i <- 0 to 1; c <- "Hello") yield (c + i).toChar
  // Yields Vector('H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 'I', 'f', 'm', 'm', 'p')
```

[End quote]

Indeed, running this in the REPL, I see that the result of the first code snippet has type String, and the second code snippet has type scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Char].

Why do the types differ? I think I understand the second line of code, but I don't understand why the first line doesn't also have type scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Char]. What magic is happening to get a String rather than a Vector? What does the author mean by "compatible with the first generator"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both `flatMap` and `map` are trying to build an object of the same type if possible. The first example is effectively:

```
"Hello".flatMap { c => (0 to 1).map { i => (c + i).toChar } }
```

since you are calling `String#flatMap` (`StringOps#flatMap` to be exact), it will try to build `String`, and it's possible because internal collection returns a collection of `Char`s (try to remove `toChar` and you will see something very different).

In the second example:

```
(0 to 1).flatMap { i => "Hello".map { c =>  yield (c + i).toChar }}
```

it's impossible to generate a valid `Range`, so `Range#flatMap` falls back to `Vector`.

Another interesting example:

```
Map(1 -> 2, 3 -> 4).map(_._1) //> List(1, 3)
```

Normally `Map#map` will try to generate `Map`, but since we don't have pairs it's impossible, so it falls back to `List`

**UPDATE**

You can even use this trick if you want to generate something different from the default (e.g. I want to generate a list of `Char`s instead):

```
for { 
  _ <- List(None) // List type doesn't matter
  c <- "Hello"
  i <- 0 to 1
} yield (c + i).toChar //> List(H, I, e, f, l, m, l, m, o, p)
```

Answer (score 2):

To see why:

```
$ scalam -Xprint:typer
Welcome to Scala 2.12.0-M5 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_92).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> for (c <- "Hello"; i <- 0 to 1) yield (c + i).toChar
[[syntax trees at end of                     typer]] // <console>
val res0: String = scala.Predef.augmentString("Hello").flatMap[Char, String](((c: Char) => scala.Predef.intWrapper(0).to(1).map[Char, scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Char]](((i: Int) => c.+(i).toChar))(immutable.this.IndexedSeq.canBuildFrom[Char])))(scala.Predef.StringCanBuildFrom);
```

The `StringCanBuildFrom` builds strings, of course.

There are many duplicates of this question, because everyone is mystified.

Answer (score 0):

The collection you are using for the first generator is the class that is used for the translation from for expression to operations as described in the [Scala Documentation](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/yield.html):

> Scala’s “for comprehensions” are syntactic sugar for composition of multiple operations with foreach, map, flatMap, filter or withFilter. Scala actually translates a for-expression into calls to those methods, so any class providing them, or a subset of them, can be used with for comprehensions.